# Run java-applet source code in a browser

Tags: java, applet, jvm

Is there way to configure JVM to run java-applet source code in a browser without compiling?

Comment: No.  That's not what JVMs do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. You have to compile it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can run an applet in a browser without compiling. You need the .class file for your browser and to get that,you need to compile the applet code first.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible, unless you find a java compiler, that works from inside of a compiled applet.